# How to receive value from multiply radio in struts2 Action

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, struts2

#### I am developing an online exam system that mainly include multiply choice.

1. I used `<input type='radio'/>` to show some options in form. But I don't know how to receive the lots of options when click the button 'submit'.
2. The datas from database have almost 100 items, and I have set pagination in *show_questions_info.jsp*, now every page show 3 questions and every question has 7 options.
3. I want to use Action to receive value if it can be done. The `<s:property value="question_code" />` is question number.

#### show_questions_info.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <s:iterator value="questionInfoBeanList" >
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><s:property value="question_code" /></td>
                        <td><s:property value="content" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="radio" name="<s:property value="question_code" />"
                               value="<s:property value="op_type_A" />" id="1">
                        <lable for="1"><s:property value="op_type_A" /></lable>

                        <input type="radio" name="<s:property value="question_code" />"
                               value="<s:property value="op_type_B" />" id="2">
                        <lable for="2"><s:property value="op_type_B" /></lable>

                        <input type="radio" name="<s:property value="question_code" />"
                               value="<s:property value="op_type_C" />" id="3">
                        <lable for="3"><s:property value="op_type_C" /></lable>

                        <input type="radio" name="<s:property value="question_code" />"
                               value="<s:property value="op_type_D" />" id="4">
                        <lable for="4"><s:property value="op_type_D" /></lable>

                        <input type="radio" name="<s:property value="question_code" />"
                               value="<s:property value="op_type_E" />" id="5">
                        <lable for="5"><s:property value="op_type_E" /></lable>

                        <input type="radio" name="<s:property value="question_code" />"
                               value="<s:property value="op_type_F" />" id="6">
                        <lable for="6"><s:property value="op_type_F" /></lable>

                        <input type="radio" name="<s:property value="question_code" />"
                               value="<s:property value="op_type_G" />" id="7">
                        <lable for="7"><s:property value="op_type_G" /></lable>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </s:iterator>
            <s:submit value="提交" />
        </form>
</html>
```

Edit history

- 2018-11-06 add a item(3) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have reference of Questions List (displayed on JSP) in action class,simply iterate that list for questionCode(since in jsp `<s:property value="question_code" />`  is used for rendering q question)

```
   for(String questionCode:questionCodes){
     System.out.println(" For questionCode= "+questionCode+" selected option ="+request.getParameter(questionCode);):
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what do you want to say. You mean use `.jsp` file to receive value. But it is doesn't work. What is questionCode in your answer and how to use it?